# Using Linq Lambda Nested Expression to join two lists

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, lambda

I have the following code:

```
        List<MyClass> list1 = GetList1Contents();
        List<MyClass> list2 = GetList2Contents();

        foreach (MyClass eachClass in list1)
        {
            List<MyClass> results = (list2.Select(x => x.History.Select(z => (z.Key == eachClass.ID))));
        }
```

MyClass contains a List called History.  What I’m trying to do is match any entries in list2 that have history entries in list 1 – but the compiler doesn’t like my syntax.

Comment: You probably want to use Where or Any (and/or a join), but it's hard to know exactly what you're trying to achieve. What is the type of the History list? What are History.Key and MyClass.ID? Please give more details.

Comment: You should use `Where` (or `Any`, `FirstOrDefault`) instead of `Select` to find items. `Select(z => z.Key == id)` actually returns an `IEnumerable<bool>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<MyClass> results = list2.Where(x => x.History.Any(z => (z.Key == eachClass.ID))).ToList();
```